# Javascript Match random text better technology

Tags: javascript, text, random, match

I have this javascript code to match random quote but sometimes it match the same quote 2 times consecutively. Can you help me?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);


function init() {

    generate();

    var enterButton = document.getElementById("haikuButton");
        enterButton.addEventListener("click", generate);

}

function generate() {

    var threeS = ["visions", "distance", "conscience", "process", "chaos"];
    var num3=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10) % threeS.length);    
    var words= document.getElementById("words").innerHTML= threeS[num3];

}
```

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the case of two consecutive random matches, then you will have to keep track of the previous match and pick another random number if you got the same as the previous one.

```
var prevRandom;
function generate() {
    var threeS = ["visions", "distance", "conscience", "process", "chaos"];
    var rand;
    do {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * threeS.length);
    } while (rand === prevRandom);
    prevRandom = rand;
    document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = threeS[rand];

}
```

FYI, I also changed your random number statement to pick a random number between `0` and `threeS.length - 1`.